# Android SlidingMenu pass variable from activity to menu

Tags: android

I use [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) in my android application. I don't want to use fragments, I use only Activity (SlidingActivity)

Here is my implementation code:

```
private void setupSlidingMenu() {
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_slidingmenu);
    SlidingMenu menu = getSlidingMenu();

    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setBehindScrollScale(0.55f);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.85f);
    menu.setBehindOffset(100);

}
```

I don't know how to change (communicate) `activity_slidingmenu` view info depend of current SlidingActivity?

For example I want to change current menu font color on current item:

[image: example]

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not that clear, could you give a better example?